# Z-Combine desaturates reflection Layer

Tags: compositing-nodes

I am trying to combine some layer in the compositor with Z-Combine but in the last step the reflection is loosing its color.

- In the **top** of the first picture you can see the part of compositing that is causing the Problem.
- In The **lower right** is the result of combining all Layers. The reflection there has still the right saturation.
- In the **lower left** ist the final Image. After i did the last Z-Combine. The reflection is **almost grey**.

[image: Screenshot - Compositor Blender 2.8]

Here i saved the image from the viewer node to manually add the background in a third party program (paint.net). The saturation of the reflection here is ok.

[image: Screenshot Paint.Net - Simple Layer]

Here is the complete compositing.
I rendered 4 Layers:

- Objects
- Shadows
- reflection
- alphachannel for reflection

[image: complete compositing]

Am i using the Z-Combine in a wrong way?

Maybe there is a better node to add the background color.

I Guess it has something to do with the alpha channel, but why is everything alright till i add the white color with the last Z-Combine?

Comment: For the background you could use the Alpha Over node.

Comment: Hi Phour, if you're not going to be combining zdepth information I'd recommend swapping those 'Z Combine' nodes with 'AlphaOver' nodes. This could fix your problem potentially

Comment: Thank you both for the respone, but sadly i get the same result with the AlphaOver node.